# jQuery/CSS: line-height of "normal" == ?px

Tags: jquery, css

I'm calling `$("#foobar").css("line-height")` and getting back "normal". How do I translate this to a pixel amount? Is "normal" defined in the CSS spec or is it browser specific?

Comment: Which browser/platform were you using? A live demo might help too (http://jsbin.com and http://jsfiddle.net are both good). Firefox 3.6.8 and Chrome 6.0.472.51 beta (on Ubuntu 10.04) both return pixel values, as expected. On SO `$('div.container').css('line-height');` returns 11.2px (FF).

Comment: Chrome on Windows XP returns `normal`

Answer (score 19):

According to [this page](http://css-class.com/test/css/text/linebox-line-height-011.html), it seems most of recent browsers use the same value for `line-height: normal` : 1.14, id est the `font-size` property with a 1.14 coefficient.

Tried with several browsers (on Windows XP) :

- Chrome 21.0.1180.75
- Firefox 14.0.1
- Safari 5.1.7
- Opera 11.64
- IE 7
- IE 8

**EDIT**

I was wrong, `line-height` depends of `font-family`, `font-size`, your browser, maybe your OS...

More reading on [Eric Meyers' website](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/05/06/line-height-abnormal/).

Comment: So does this mean "line-height: 1.14em" is the equivalent but explicit statement?

Comment: I assumed it, but it's not true. `line-height` depends of `font-family`, `font-size`, your browser, maybe your OS... You'll find some reading on [Eric Meyers' website](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/05/06/line-height-abnormal/)

Comment: Still Zeplin thinks it's a useful value to give to developers :S

Answer (score 8):

Normal is actually referred to as `abnormal` on [several instances](http://www.htmlprimer.com/musings-line-height-normal) as there is quite a browser inconsistency.

> declaring line-height: normal not only
>   vary from browser to browser, which I
>   had expected—in fact, quantifying
>   those differences was the whole
>   point—but they also vary from one font
>   face to another, and can also vary
>   within a given face.

Comment: I thought it worth offering a link back to Eric Meyer's site for the source of your quote, for a fascinating read: http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2008/05/06/line-height-abnormal/

Comment: -1 since this doesn't come close to answering the question. Good info, but should have been a comment.

Comment: @MartinJespersen I am not going to delete the answer as, even after reading it now, I still think I answered correctly as `normal` is browser specific and, therefore, inconsistent across browser and should not be translated to pixels. That said I am very appreciative you took the time to provide feedback about the downvote, thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

`normal` is a valid setting for `line-height` so there isn't really a way around that for the browsers that will return that.

Alternatively, you can use `.css('height')` , as it will count only the interior section of an element, not padding/border/margin. It would take a little creativity if you had a multi-line element, or an element with more than just text in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/xVBfb/

**Edit:** An example of a work around would be having

`<span id='def' style='line-height:inherit;display:none;'>&nbsp;</span>`

within the element, then to find the line height you could just use the `.height()` of #def as it will always be only one line and thus, the line height of the parent element.

---

Chrome in Windows XP is an example of a browser that returns `normal` in that jsfiddle unless explicitly specified otherwise. Firefox returns a pixel count. `normal` is the initial value per w3 spec.
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height

Comment: Apparently the workaround you provided seems to be the best option. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly calculating normal line-height in pixel is difficult. Though, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) it's roughly 1.2em.

If you've:

```
body{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

So, your website has normal font-size as 16px then the normal line-height would be roughly `24px`. This means you can calculate normal font-size pixel value multiplied by `1.5` that is `16px * 1.5 == 24px`

Notice: I didn't multiplied by 1.2 because there's difference between px value and em value.

Comment: A small hint: _take control_ of the browser(s) initial values and never use _normal_. As many remember the old `font-size: 101% hack` and many other things, one approach as of 2018 is to _reset_ html, and use the `rem` unit value when wanting "normal" on any other element like `html { line-height: 1.15; font-size: 10px; }` and then `body { line-height: 1.3125; font-size: 1.6rem; }` = consistant `16px font size` and `21px line-height`. Then use `line-height: 2.1rem;` to normalize elements if you concider 21px as normal. (just devide XX px with 10 to get rem: 1.2rem = 12px, 2.0rem = 20px).

Answer (score 0):

However this was written a long time ago but helped me to wrote temporary solution in my task. I'm copying this code than maybe other people can use it.

```
$('#lineHeightInc')
.click(function() {
    var box = GetSelectedBox();
    var ct = box.data('LineHeight');
    if (isNaN(ct))
        ct = 0;
    ct++;
    box.css('line-height', (parseFloat(box.css('font-size')) * 1.61 + ct) + 'px');
    box.data('LineHeight', ct);
});

$('#lineHeightDic')
.click(function () {
    var box = GetSelectedBox();
    var ct = box.data('LineHeight');
    if (isNaN(ct))
        ct = 0;
    ct--;
    box.css('line-height', (parseFloat(box.css('font-size')) * 1.61 + ct) + 'px');
    box.data('LineHeight', ct);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can understand and utilize the CSS line-height property:

Syntax for CSS Line-Height:

**line-height**: normal | number | length | initial | inherit;

As you delve into using CSS line-height values, keep this guide close:

**Normal**: This is the standard line height and is typically about 1.2 on most desktop browsers, but it can vary depending on the font family used.

**Length**: Specify an exact line height using units like cm, pt, or px. This measurement will define the height of your line boxes.

**Percentage**: Set the line height relative to the element's font size. This allows for scalable and responsive design.

**Number**: Inputting a number will multiply with the current font size to derive the line height. This method is often preferred for its consistency and predictable results.

**Initial**: Resets the property to its default value, as defined by the CSS specifications.

**Inherit**: The line height is taken from the parent element, ensuring consistency in inherited styling.

Refer to these definitions as you work with the line-height property to enhance the readability and design of your text elements.