# JavaScript to avoid widows

Tags: javascript, css, typography

A common problem when working with typography in HTML/CSS is something we call "horunge" in Swedish ("[widow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widows_and_orphans)" in english).

**What it is:**

Let's say you have a box with a width of 200px and with the text "I love typograpy very much". Now the text breaks and becomes:

> I love typography very
>   much

As a designer I don't want a word bastard (single word / row). If this was a document/PDF etc. I would break the word before very and look like this:

> I love typography
>   very much

which looks much better.

Can I solve this with a CSS rule or with a javascript? The rule should be to never let a word stand empty on a row.

I know it can be solved by adding a `<br />` but that's not a solution that works with dynamic widths, feed content, different translations, browser font rendering issues etc.

**Update (solution)**
I solved my problem with this jquery plugin: http://matthewlein.com/widowfix/

Comment: Widows... Word bastard... I love Swedish! :)

Answer (score 8):

A simple jQuery / regrex solution could look like the following, if you add the class "noWidows" to the tag of any element that contains text you are worried about.

Such as:

```
<p class="noWidows">This is a very important body of text.</p>
```

And then use this script:

```
$('.noWidows').each(function(i,d){
   $(d).html( $(d).text().replace(/\s(?=[^\s]*$)/g, "&nbsp;") )
});
```

This uses regex to find and replace the last space in the string with a non-breaking character. Which means the last two words will be forced onto the same line. It's a good solution if you have space around the end of the line because this could cause the text to run outside of an element with a fixed width, or if not fixed, cause the element to become larger.

Comment: Would be nice if this didn't break html inside of said elements.

Comment: This strips any formatting within that HTML such as strong, anchors, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add to this page as it helped me a lot.

If you have (widows) actually should be orphans as widows are single words that land on the next page and not single words on a new line.

Working with postcodes like "N12 5GG" will result in the full postcode being on a new line together but still classed as an orphan so a work around is this. (changed the class to "noWidow2" so you can use both versions.

123 Some_road, Some_town, N12 5GG

```
$('.noWidows2').each(function(i,d){ 
    var value="&nbsp;"
    $(d).html($(d).text().replace(/\s(?=[^\s]*$)/g, value).replace(/\s(?=[^\s]*$)/g, value)); 
});
```

This will result is the last 3 white spaces being on a new line together making the postcode issue work.

End Result

```
123 Some_road,
Some_town, N12 5GG
```

Answer (score 0):

There are also CSS widows and orphans properties: see the [about.com article](http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blsporphans.htm).

Not sure about browser support...

EDIT: more information about WebKit implementation here: https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=orphans.

Comment: Those two only work for printing http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/page.html#break-inside

Comment: @c69 You're right. Anyone know of any plans to add this for non-paged media? Can't find anything on the web. It'd be great to see some more typography tools like this (and flow and runaround) implemented for screen media.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-regions/#best-region-breaks - some of this stuff works in IE10 pp3, and will also work in new WebKit.

Comment: @c69 more information about WebKit implementation here: https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=orphans.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little [script here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qz4qc/), with the help of [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392868/javascript-find-divs-line-height-not-css-property-but-actual-line-height/4515470#4515470) to find line height.

It's just an approach, it may or may not work, didn't have time to test throughly.

As of now, `text_element` must be a jQuery object.

```
function avoidBastardWord( text_element )
{
    var string = text_element.text();
    var parent = text_element.parent();
    var parent_width =  parent.width();
    var parent_height = parent.height();

    // determine how many lines the text is split into
    var lines = parent_height / getLineHeight(text_element.parent()[0]);

    // if the text element width is less than the parent width,
    // there may be a widow
    if ( text_element.width() < parent_width )
    {
        // find the last word of the entire text
        var last_word =  text_element.text().split(' ').pop();

        // remove it from our text, creating a temporary string
        var temp_string = string.substring( 0, string.length - last_word.length - 1);

        // set the new one-word-less text string into our element
        text_element.text( temp_string );

        // check lines again with this new text with one word less
        var new_lines = parent.height() / getLineHeight(text_element.parent()[0]); 

        // if now there are less lines, it means that word was a widow
        if ( new_lines != lines )
        {
            // separate each word
            temp_string = string.split(' ');

            // put a space before the second word from the last
            // (the one before the widow word)
            temp_string[ temp_string.length - 2 ] = '<br>' + temp_string[ temp_string.length - 2 ] ;

            // recreate the string again
            temp_string = temp_string.join(' ');

            // our element html becomes the string
            text_element.html( temp_string );
        }
        else
        {
            // put back the original text into the element
            text_element.text( string );
        }

    }

}
```

Different browsers have different font settings. Try to play a little to see the differences. I tested it on IE8 and Opera, modifying the string every time and it seemed to work ok.

I would like to hear some feedback and improve because I think it may come in handy anyway.

Just play with it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Manually, you could replace the space in between with `&nbsp;`

I've been looking for ways to dynamically add it in. I found a few, but haven't been able to make it work myself.

Comment: that should be with "& n b s p ;" (without spaces in between, & non-breaking space)

Comment: wrap code between two ` symbols to allow proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('span').each(function() {
  var w = this.textContent.split(" ");
  if (w.length > 1) {
    w[w.length - 2] += "&nbsp;" + w[w.length - 1];
    w.pop();
    this.innerHTML = (w.join(" "));
  }
});
```

```css
#foo {
  width: 124px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <span class="orphan">hello there I am a string really really long, I wonder how many lines I have</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: This strips any formatting within that HTML such as strong, anchors, etc.