# Last line of a paragraph contains a single word only

Tags: css, paragraph, orphan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript to avoid widows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444656/javascript-to-avoid-widows)

Is there a way in CSS or maybe JS to prevent having paragraphs where the last line contains only one word ?

Comment: What you want to achieve? What have you tried?

Comment: See thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444656/javascript-to-avoid-widows

Comment: exact duplicate of @BenBrooks link