# How to get the size of a row in a text with Jquery without ".css('lineHeight');" and ".css(font-size);"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, line, font-size

Hi I'm having problems developing with Samsung Smart TV SDK, which use javascript (I'm using JQuery for most part of code). I need to get the size of a row in a div but in Samsung TV 2011 the

```
$('#element').css('font-size')
```

and

```
$('#element').css('line-height')
```

doesn't work (it's a software problem about 2011 because in 2012 and 2013 work correctly).
Anyone know how to get the size of a row in Jquery or javascript without this two methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say a `row`, what is the actual element that you're talking about?

Comment: You can try offsetHeight: document.getElementById("element").offsetHeight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually want to return the line height use this...

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
        var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

Then use it like...

```
getStyle('#test', 'line-height' )
```

From here... [JavaScript: Find DIV's line-height, not CSS property but actual line-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392868/javascript-find-divs-line-height-not-css-property-but-actual-line-height)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stucked with this all day!

Answer (score 2):

Try with `outerHeight()`:

```
var height = $('#element').outerHeight();
```

Or maybe you are looking for innerHeight():

```
var height = $('#element').innerHeight();
```

Comment: `$('#element').outerHeight(true)` to include the element's margin in the calculation.

Comment: @Joe ya but i don't think OP wants to include it

Comment: I thought I would put it out there for anyone who might benefit.  :)

Comment: I don't need the height of the element, I need the line height value of the element.