# HTML: one row of <textarea> is of how much height?

Tags: html, height, textarea, row, row-height

I want to know the height of one row of <`textarea>`. I want to know that because I want to do some calculations.

Do we know it or do we have to do some scripting?

Comment: If you just want to know the number of rows there are, just split by `\r\n` `\r` `\n` respectively.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The height of a row is set by `line-height`.

For example:

```
<textarea rows="1">hello world</textarea>
```

If you set the following:

```
textarea { line-height: 1; font-size: 12px; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

By inspecting the textarea element you'll find out that it has a height of 12px.

Answer (score 3):

Basically it is the same as whatever the `line-height` is set to. You can either set it explicitly, or figure out what it is set to, and go from there.

[Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/osoniy/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

You could also determine the value of `line-height` (or any style) by using `currentStyle` or `getComputedStyle`, as per this answer for ***getting the line-height of a div***:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4392968/142714

And if you have jQuery you can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), which abstracts the above (there are browser differences to consider).