# Get line-height of p tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to figure out the line-height of a `<p>` tag within a div.

```js
var myp = document.getElementById('myp');
var heightLabel = document.getElementById('heightLabel');
heightLabel.innerHTML = myp.style.lineHeight + " is the height.";
```

```html
    <div> 
      <p id=myp>People assume I'm a boiler ready to explode, <br>but I actually have very low blood pressure, <br>which is shocking to people.</p>
    </div>
    
    <h3 id="heightLabel"></h3>
```

However, as seen in the code above, if the line-height of the p tag is not explicitly assigned then using `.style.lineHeight` returns an empty string.

Is there any way to get the height of a line in a `<p>` tag if it hasn't been assigned? I'd like to get it in px at the end.

Comment: You need the computed style not the style property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `.style` property, you need to `getComputedStyle()` of your `p` element

```
var elementStyle = window.getComputedStyle(*DOM element*);
```

After that you can simply use `elementStyle.getPropertyValue(*style-property*)` prop.

Btw. you can check computed style under your console (firefox screenshot):

[image]

See working example:

```js
var myp = document.getElementById('myp');
var heightLabel = document.getElementById('heightLabel');
var mypStyle = window.getComputedStyle(myp);
heightLabel.innerHTML = mypStyle.getPropertyValue('line-height') + " is the line height.";

// console.log(mypStyle.getPropertyValue('line-height')); // output 20px 
// console.log(typeof mypStyle.getPropertyValue('line-height')); // string

// Using parseFloat we convert string into value
// Examples: 
// parseFloat('20px') // 20, typeof number
// parseFloat('22.5rem') // 22.5 typeof number
// If you are sure, your string will always contain intenger value use parseInt() instead
// DOES not work cross-browser
// Chrome return line-height normal, firefox '20px'
// var getNumberValue = parseFloat(mypStyle.getPropertyValue('line-height')); // 20, typeof string

console.log(getLineHeight(myp));


// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392868/javascript-find-divs-line-height-not-css-property-but-actual-line-height?noredirect=1&lq=1
function getLineHeight(element){
   var temp = document.createElement(element.nodeName);
   temp.setAttribute("style","margin:0px;padding:0px;font-family:"+element.style.fontFamily+";font-size:"+element.style.fontSize);
   temp.innerHTML = "test";
   temp = element.parentNode.appendChild(temp);
   var ret = temp.clientHeight;
   temp.parentNode.removeChild(temp);
   return ret;
}
```

```html
<div> 
      <p id=myp>People assume I'm a boiler ready to explode, <br>but I actually have very low blood pressure, <br>which is shocking to people.</p>
    </div>
    
    <h3 id="heightLabel"></h3>
```

Comment: Is there any way to translate `normal` to numeric units?

Comment: @MarksCode I've updated my answer, see my comments. I explained how to get only "20" from "20px" string and cast it to typeof number. If it helped you let me know, don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: Getting an error when running snippet: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of nul`

Comment: @MarksCode at what line? `mypStyle.getPropertyValue('line-height').match(/\d+/)[0]`? What is output for `mypStyle.getPropertyValue('line-height')`?

Comment: @MarksCode Ok, one more edit. Instead of matching digits we use `parseFloat()`, if you are sure your value will be always intenger use `parseInt()` instead. See updated answer.

Comment: getting `NaN number`

Comment: For what value?

Comment: Ok, I see the error, let me fix it. Firefox correctly shows the number, but chrome does not.

Comment: Once again I've updated my answer. Line-height is different for all browsers, thats my we have to use small trick. It's a solution from another question. Chrome output is `18` but ff is `20`.