# How to add padding or margin of exactly 1 line-height

Tags: css

I want to add bottom padding to the `ul` (or to the last `li`) that is *exactly equal* to the computed value of the `line-height` property at `ul` and `li` (they both inherit their `line-height`). In other words, I want white space under "Item 3" of the same size as if an "Item 4" `li` was added. Is that possible?

Note that `em` and `rem` units don't achieve this if `line-height` is not equal to 1. Also, consider that the "environment" in which the `ul` lives is unknown. For example, I don't know if `body` has `line-height: 1.1`, `line-height: 2`, etc.

I want to have the blue space in this image as padding.

[image]

This achieves the desired look, but it just feels wrong to have to use pseudo-elements for such a simple use-case.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul::after {
  content: "\00a0";
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you mean the value of the computed value of line-height if this one is set to `1`?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I mean the computed `line-height` value for the `li` element.

Comment: If you are using SASS/LESS, then you can define a `variable` and read the value of `line-height` and `padding` from that variable

Comment: and by the way, CSS has variables as well.

Comment: @rach8garg This is true, but then the styling doesn't adjust itself automatically based on its computed `line-height` which can come from any parent HTML element.

Comment: @rach8garg even CSS variable won't help here, because it's about a computed value that we don't set explicitely .. if you set `1.3` to line height you don't have the computed value since it's relative to font

Comment: _“but it just feels wrong to have to use pseudo-elements for such a simple use-case”_ - that is something one could get over though, I feel :-) If you have ever used `float` in the past to achieve any kind of column layout, then you are familiar already with the “abuse” of CSS features for stuff they were never actually intended for in the first place, so … I’d probably accept an already found working solution, and not try to find a different one just for the heck of it.

Comment: So why can't we set value of padding and line-height relative to parent/root in em/rem ? They both will be computed as same if I am not mistaken. Similar to variable example I gave below.

Comment: @rach8garg and what if we want to keep the default line-height and don't set it?

Comment: @04FS yes of course I can get over it :) I'm asking this to know if I'm lacking something useful in my knowledge of CSS. The answer could very well be that there is no other way.

Comment: I guess you could say knowing when to apply such “tricks”/workarounds to achieve a certain desired effect, _is_ a large part of useful CSS knowledge :-) Introducing a fake “line” of text via the line-break in a pseudo element lets you reap the benefits of an already built-in mechanism, anything else that did not make use of that automatism in some form or other would mean you’d have to do some sort of calculation or specify some magic number somewhere … so this is probably as good as it gets.

Comment: Well, its easy .. is not possible using CSS to dynamically set the `padding-bottom`. Either use what you already did with a `::psuedo element` or use `javascript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the computed `line-height` just using *CSS*. So with that said, its not possible to dynamicaly change the `padding-bottom` based on the `line-height` with *CSS* only.

So either do what you already did using the `::pseudo` element, which can take its *parent* height. Acting as a new `<li>` element.

Or use `JavaScript`, that could be done like this

```js
var ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
var li = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');

for(var i = 0;i < ul.length;i++) {
  ul[i].style.paddingBottom = li[0].clientHeight + 'px';
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

[JavaScript: Find DIV's line-height, not CSS property but actual line-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392868/javascript-find-divs-line-height-not-css-property-but-actual-line-height)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight

> This achieves the desired look, but it just feels wrong to have to use pseudo-elements for such a simple use-case.

There is nothing wrong to use `::pseudo` elements for such a use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Total height of `<ul>` is 80px and each item has line-height of 20px.

```css
:root {
  --custom-height: 20px; 
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: var(--custom-height);
}
li{
   line-height: var(--custom-height);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This can work if the `line-height` is fixed. In my case, I'm looking for something that adjusts to its computed property value though.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using jquery, But the approach you've applied is better than jquery approach. see below example.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var get_padding = $('ul>li').css('font-size');
  $('ul>li:last-child').css('padding-bottom',get_padding);
});
```

```css
ul {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the pseudo element would be a lot better than using jQuery I guess

Comment: I've already told that bro..., Couldn't understand negative votes...I just gave other option.

Comment: If `line-height` is not 1, (e.g. `line-height: 2;`) then the padding will not match the line height of an item. From a quick search, getting the computed `line-height` value using jquery is not a straightforward task. This might help others searching for this though.

Comment: because your answer is wrong, this will only work in one particular case when line-height is equal to `1`