# jQuery: how to make css('line-height') work cross-browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I'm supporting IE8 and up.

```
$(something).css('line-height');
```

In Chrome this returns `32px` but in IE8 it returns `normal`

How do I get around this? Maybe a native javascript variation?

Comment: you can set line-height:32px on css

Comment: did you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614323/jquery-css-line-height-of-normal-px ?

Comment: adding some element and retrieving its clientHeight will give some "px" even on IE

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is a webkit vs. IE issue. Not sure about FF, but there are a couple options for how to fix it. Overtly specifying a pixel value will work. But I don't like doing that because it's harder to keep things in proportion if you scale the text, etc with media queries. I was able to get it working by overtly specifying the line-height in `em`s (rather then letting it inherit). It's also relevant that it was previously set to `rem`s which IE8 doesn't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function lineHeight(element){
       var tmp=$("<div>test</div>");
       element.append(tmp);
       tmp.css({"padding":"0","margin":"0","border":"0"});
       var height = tmp[0].clientHeight;
       tmp.remove();
       return height;
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RFHKH/) in FF and Chrome return 20px but on IE8 18px