# CSS line-height not the same in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

Goal: Just show the first four lines in a text box.

I tested [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/utcvwucs/5/) with Chrome 43.0.2357.132 (64-bit) and Firefox 39 and in Chrome the text box shows perfectly the first 4 lines (remaining lines are hidden) whereas in Firefox the `line-height` appears larger, therefore the fourth line got cut.

How can I solve this with CSS?

```css
.txt {
    width:300px;
    height:48px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#aaaaaa;
    margin-bottom:2em;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">
    This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. 
</div>
```

Comment: Is the default font-size on all browsers the same? You set a height in `px`, but a font-size in `em`. You might want to declare the line-height to (making it overrule any default value, if given).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could explicitly set the `line-height`.

```
line-height: 1.2;
```

#### Working Example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6an0b1oc/)):

```css
.txt {
    width:300px;
    height:48px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#aaaaaa;
    margin-bottom:2em;
    font-size:0.8em;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">
    This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. 
</div>
```

It appears Firefox has a default `line-height` of `1.1`, but Chrome has a default `line-height` of `1.2`.

Comment: This worked for me only, if I also declared `Arial` as font for `body`, it seems that Firefox39 chooses `Helvetica` as default font?

Comment: Setting the line-height explicitly (as I do this anyhow) didn’t help for me. There IS definitely a difference between the result in Firefox and Safari. I.g. line-height: 1.5em; does not end up in the same pixel reality on both browsers.

Comment: It seems that the difference becomes more notable on smaller font sizes. It helped to use absolute pixel values instead. Weird.

Comment: At the time of writing (2020), you may get different results on Firefox and Chrome, even if you explicitly set font-size in px and line-height to a multiplier.  This is a known bug in Chrome - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1023654.  Firefox will multiply the two values and retain any fractional pixel, whereas Chrome will round down to the nearest integer pixel.  For example, if you render `<p style='font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.75;'>Text</p>` on both browsers you will get 24.5px on Firefox and 24px on Chrome.

Comment: JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8f3mb4kw/ - in Chrome, inspect the paragraph with DevTools, go to the Computed tab, and you will see line-height: 24.5px and height: 24px.  The rounding should not be occurring.

Answer (score 6):

In general the default `line-height` value is `normal`, on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) it says:

> `normal` - Depends on the user agent. Desktop browsers (including
>   Firefox) use a default value of **roughly** 1.2, depending on the
>   element's `font-family`.

To fix the inconsistency results from different browsers, you could try apply a `number` or `length` or `percentage` value for it, also specify a web-safe font for `font-family`.

Also see this related post - [jQuery/CSS: line-height of “normal” == ?px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614323/jquery-css-line-height-of-normal-px)

```css
.txt {
    width:300px;
    height:47px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
    margin-bottom:2em;
    font-size:0.8em;
    font-family:arial; /*new*/
    line-height:1.2; /*new*/
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">
    This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Line-height is only part of the solution.

As the other answers state, it varies by browser and you will want to set the value for greater consistency. My suggestion is to use `em` values.

Secondly, you will want the height of your container to be a multiple of the line-height. So, if you want a container that is 4 lines high and your line-height is 1.2em, then you will want a container height of 4.8em (1.2em x 4 lines).

```css
.txt {
    width:300px;
    height:4.8em; /*4x the line-height to show 4 lines that are not cropped */
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#aaaaaa;
    margin-bottom:2em;
    font-size:0.8em;
    line-height:1.2em; /* set a relative line height */
}
```

```html
<div class="txt">
    This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. This is just a temporary text. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Each browser has a different default font-family, so you should specify the font-family.

```
.txt {
    width:300px;
    height:48px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#aaaaaa;
    margin-bottom:2em;
    font-size:0.8em;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add line height code for mozilla using:

```
 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    *,body{
        line-height: as per your requirement;
    }
    }
```