# How to make the background image as scrollable in the textarea HTML element?

Tags: html, css, firefox, frontend, web-frontend

We are facing a background image issue in Firefox, we want a note design using text-area HTML element and we faced this issue when I enter the content above the limit in chrome the background image is scrolling with the content and same in Firefox the background image is fixed, and after using the browser compatibility CSS properties also it is not working and I have checked all the possible ways to achieve/create a note design using the text-area and I am attaching the result I got in chrome and Firefox and if I were made mistake please let me know I will look into it.

[Firefox(112.0.2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OC71P.png)

[Firefox(112.0.2 Issue)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5Edq.png)

Chrome
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/17082686?key=941cf4fac871a3108799338a0b2227ef

```
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, transparent 42px, var(--theme-blue) 45px);
background-attachment: scroll;
```

Comment: We can't help you until and unless you post your actual HTML and CSS, not screenshots.

Comment: This approach is flawed for the simple reason that `<textarea>` is a _replaced element_: what appears on-screen is entirely at the discretion of the browser's layout engine, which means that a "lined paper" `background-image` like yours must assume that the textarea's line-height is consistent (hint: it isn't) and is always 42px (second hint: it isn't).

Comment: Basically, [the only approaches that could come remotely close to what you're after](https://codepen.io/MarcMalignan/pen/QbaXGg) rely on setting a fixed `line-height:` inside the `<textarea>`, but you won't be able to make those fake lines match the baseline of the text, simpy because CSS (still) doesn't expose any control over that (and [don't try converting `line-height: normal;` to `px`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614323/jquery-css-line-height-of-normal-px) because you can't: it's undefined)

Comment: here's the Bugzilla entry for Firefox btw: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1007064